# Maximum average, minimum average, and average

Tags: java, average

I am unsure on how to get the maximum average, minimum average, and average of everything in total. I already set variables with values for them in my code, however I am not sure how to input the averages in my code. Any help would be great! Thanks.
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Averages {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int max = 0;
        int min = 9000;
        int score = 0;
        int n;
        int c;
        int rowMaxNumber = 0;
        int rowMinNumber = 0;
        int columnMax = 0;
        int columnMin = 0;
        int averageMin = 0;
        int averageMax = 0;
        double average = 0;

        System.out.println("How many rows?");
        n = scan.nextInt();

        for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
            System.out.println("How many student in row " + row + "?");
            c = scan.nextInt();

            for (int column = 1; column <= c; column++) {
                System.out.println("Score for student " + column + " in row "
                        + row + "?");
                score = scan.nextInt();

                rowMaxNumber = row;
                columnMax = column;

                rowMinNumber = row;
                columnMin = column;

            }
            if (score >= max) {
                max = score;

            }
            if (score < min) {
                min = score;

            }

        }
        System.out.println("Student " + columnMax + " of row " + rowMaxNumber
                + " was highest with " + max);
        System.out.println("Student " + columnMin + " of row " + rowMinNumber
                + " was lowest with " + min);
        System.out.println("Row " + rowMaxNumber + " had highest average with "
                + averageMax);
        System.out.println("Row " + rowMinNumber + " had lowest average with "
                + averageMax);
        System.out.println("Class average is " + average);
    }
}
```

Comment: I might add some clarity to your variables - `row_max_number` or `rowMaxNumber`. They're hard to read.

Comment: Sorry about that, I made the change you suggested to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to get the maximum average, minimum average, and total average. Thanks for anybody that helped!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Averages 
{
 public static void main ( String[] args )
  {
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int max = -9999;
        int min = 9999;
        int score = 0;
        int n;
        int c;
        int rowsum = 0;
        int rowMaxNumber = 0;
        int rowMinNumber = 0;
        int columnMax = 0;
        int columnMin = 0;
        double averageMin = 9999;
        double averageMax = 0;
        double avg = 0.0;
        double avgTotal = 0.0;
        double totalScore = 0;
        double totalStudent = 0;            

        System.out.println("How many rows?");
        n = scan.nextInt();

        for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
            System.out.println("How many student in row " + row + "?");
            rowsum=0;
            c = scan.nextInt();
            totalStudent += c;

            for (int column = 1; column <= c; column++) {

                System.out.println("Score for student " + column + " in row " + row + "?");
                score = scan.nextInt();
                rowsum += score;
                totalScore += score;     

                if (score >= max) {
                    max = score;
                    columnMax = column;

                }
                if (score < min) {
                    min = score;
                    columnMin = column;
                }
            }
            avg = rowsum/c;
            if( avg >= averageMax){
                averageMax=avg;
                rowMaxNumber = row;

            }
            if( avg < averageMin){
                averageMin=avg;
                rowMinNumber = row;
            }
        }
        avgTotal = totalScore/totalStudent;

        System.out.println("Student " + columnMax + " of row " + rowMaxNumber + " was highest with " + max);
        System.out.println("Student " + columnMin + " of row " + rowMinNumber + " was lowest with " + min);
        System.out.println("Row " + rowMaxNumber + " had highest average with " + averageMax);
        System.out.println("Row " + rowMinNumber + " had lowest average with " + averageMin);
        System.out.println("Class average is " + avgTotal);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Averages {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int max = 0;
    int min = 9000;
    int score = 0;
    int n;
    int c;
    int rowsum = 0;
    int rowmaxnumber = 0;
    int rowminnumber = 0;
    int columnmax = 0;
    int columnmin = 0;
    int averagemin = 9999;
    int averagemax = 0;
    double average = 0;

    System.out.println("How many rows?");
    n = scan.nextInt();

    for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
        System.out.println("How many student in row " + row + "?");
        c = scan.nextInt();
        rowsum = 0;
        for (int column = 1; column <= c; column++) {

            System.out.println("Score for student " + column + " in row "
                    + row + "?");
            score = scan.nextInt();
            rowsum += score;
            rowmaxnumber = row;
            columnmax = column;

            rowminnumber = row;
            columnmin = column;

            if (score >= max) {
                max = score;
            }
            if (score < min) {
                min = score;
            }

        }
        int avg=rowsum/c;
        if( avg >= averagemax){
            averagemax=avg;
        }
        if( avg <= averagemin){
            averagemin=avg;
        }




    }
    System.out.println("Student " + columnmax + " of row " + rowmaxnumber
            + " was highest with " + max);
    System.out.println("Student " + columnmin + " of row " + rowminnumber
            + " was lowest with " + min);
    System.out.println("Row " + rowmaxnumber + " had highest average with "
            + averagemax);
    System.out.println("Row " + rowminnumber + " had lowest average with "
            + averagemin);
    System.out.println("Class average is " + average);
}
```

}

I have restructured some code to calculate sum of scores as we see them in a row, and calculate the average on end of scanning row, also avg will give the average by dividing rowsum by no. of students in row, and then avg is compared with the previous highest and previous lowest averages. Just like you do it with score! Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out how to get the averages and posted the answer, thank you for the help nonetheless!